# how to allow edit access of product attribute based on Admin user role?

Tags: magento2

There is a custom product attribute that is being saved from the product edit page. But I want to allow access to specific admin users and not all admin users.

how to achieve the same?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
  <extension_attributes for="Path\To\Interface">
    <attribute code="name_of_attribute" type="datatype">
       <resources>
          <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::Resource_name"/>
       </resources>
    </attribute>
</extension_attributes>
```

you can give permission using extension_attributes.xml file where  you can assign specific resource to edit the attribute permission